# How to access route path from a Class method in a controller? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a class method in application_controller.rb:

```
def self.method1
  path = some_path
end
```

Now it seems I can't access some_path since usually I'll need to use route in a controller (instance method).

What is the best way to access routes here?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work from anywhere in your application

```
path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.some_path
```

Comment: Working like charm, Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

you may simply get the path using the following line of code

```
def foo
  path = request.path
end
```